# Magento OAuth, plugin install

Tags: php, magento, plugins, oauth, token

As a plugin developer, I would love to make it easy for my Magento customers to install my plugin without having to manually go through the process of downloading the zip, uploading it manually inside of the admin etc.

One solution would be to ask for their password, but no one will probably trust me with that. So I'm wondering if there's any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you ensure your module meets the [stylistic and security requirements](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/), then submit it to [Magento Connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/).

Firstly they need to obtain an installation key from Magento Connect:

[image: find a module, then get a key]

Customers can then install your extension from within their Magento installation:

[image: install the module with Connect]

This is the "standard" for distributing Magento modules to the public, especially non-developers.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, will definitely check that out!